# Using find with -exec rm in a bash script fails, but works at prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

This is driving me nuts as I know it is something easy, but I can't seem to find the solution. Arrgh! I just need to add a find command in to my script so it removes older files before running a new backup. I'd rather control this through variables instead of typing out the exact command. The command does work in the script if I type it out in there instead of using variables.

```
FIND="/usr/bin/find"
BUILD="~/"
FINDOPTS="-type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -rf {} \;"
echo $find $BUILD $FINDOPTS
## remove the 2 week old backup
echo "Removing old backups... "
$FIND $BUILD $FINDOPTS
```

If I just echo the `$FIND $BUILD $FINDOPTS` command it shows just like the command does if I type it out. Only difference is it will actually run when I type it.

Typing out `/usr/bin/find ~/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -rf {} \;` works just fine.

The error that I get is:

```
/usr/bin/find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Can anyone help explain why this is? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notwithstanding better overall solutions, here's the reason why it failed in this script:

```
FINDOPTS="-type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -rf {} \;"
                                            ^
```

The parameter `find` is waiting for is the character `;`. Since `;` is (not really by accident) *also* the shell's end of command delimiter, it has to be escaped in a shell command, hence usually typed `\;`. If now you put this character in a variable, it won't ever be evaluated by the shell as a delimiter. Thus it *musn't* be escaped.

Reproducing the error without variable:

```
$ find /etc -exec ls "\;"
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

So just replace the string with:

```
FINDOPTS="-type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -rf {} ;"
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my issue and you explained it nicely so that I understand exactly what is happening here. Really great answer, for me, at least.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `find [...] -exec rm`, I suggest using the built-in functionality:

```
find [...] -delete
```

From the manual:

```
 -delete
         Delete found files and/or directories.  Always returns true.  This executes 
         from the current working directory as find recurses down the tree.  It will 
         not attempt to delete a filename with a ``/'' character in its pathname 
         relative to ``.'' for security reasons.  Depth-first traversal processing 
         is implied by this option.  Following symlinks is incompatible with this 
         option.
```

(as an aside, you do realize that the command in your question will delete *any* files older than three days since their last modification, yes?)

Comment: Nice -- I never used `-delete` whenever using `find` commands for some reason. Always `-exec` or some `xargs`. I'll consider it for the future. Yeah, I just put a quick and dirty version in the example to find out where the issue was. The real command has some more specification in it and its not in the actual `~/` folder. Thanks tho!